# Can't format code in VS Code

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-code

I've added the following to the *keybindings.json* file.

```
[
  { "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+d",
  "command": "editor.action.format",
  "when": "editorHasFormattingProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" }
]
```

My understanding was that it would allow me to format the code by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> but nothing happens in the file when I do. I've set the indent to 2 (default in settings and in the status bar) but all the code stays at 4 spaces anyway.

How can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: This might possibly be more appropriate for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Abion47 Not sure about that. I've seen quite a few questions on the config here on SO and those were well received. And one can also claim that coding the JSON files **is** programming, hehe. However, I do see your point so I'll consider to post it there as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jim Yes, it seems to work. That's the default shortcut. The problem is that I did altered the keybindings, as shown in the question. I also changed the number of spaces from 4 to 2 for indentation, which seem not be respected by VS Code. Any idea how to resolve it? If so, post it as a reply so I can accept it.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I'm unsure ... when I test this everything works fine, also when overriding the default shortcut to ctrl+k ctrl+d